# Rearrangement of sequence of numbers.

Tags: combinatorics

I have 12 numbers, 1 to 12. I have to rearrange the sequence so that only one terms is lower than the one directly preceding: e.g. 1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 9 10 11 12 where 6 is less than 7.

The idea I have for my solution is that I split it into two groups of increasing sequences, but with the smallest term in the second sequence smaller than the largest term in the first sequence.

That way I get sequences like 1 2 3 7 9 10, 4 5 6 8 11 12.

But I don't know how to handle all the cases: e.g. if this sequence was reversed. Can I have a complete proof solution?

Comment: Are you trying to count them? Or list all of them?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848339/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744172

Comment: When a problem is complex, a good strategy is often to search for problems very similar, but more simple. And step by step, answer to the original problem. In other words, which intermediate steps could you imagine for this problem ?